# Is it possible to save multiple data to a database column

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Hi all i have my database structure as follows

```
 Field        Type
FileHeader    longblob
BatchHeader   longblob
Entry         longblob
BtchEntry     longblob
FileControl   longblob
```

I will have the data to be inserted is as follows

```
101 111111111 1111111111104021031A094101                                                      
52201               1                   1         PPD1         110402110402   1111000020000001
6221110000251                00000000011              1                     1 0111000020000001
822000000100111000020000000000000000000000011                                  111000020000001
52251               1                   1         CCD1         110402110402   1111000020000002
6281110000251                00000000011              1                     1 0111000020000002
822500000100111000020000000000010000000000001                                  111000020000002
9000006000001000000060066600012000000000003000000000003
```

as you can observe there are multiple lines that starts with 5,6 and 8. I would like to save those individually to the corresponding columns of my table. Is it possible to do if so can any mention the best method to do it. If unclear please specify

The code i written is

```
 using (StreamReader srRead = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (srRead.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            strLine = srRead.ReadLine();
            if (strLine.StartsWith("1"))
            {
                strFileHeader = strLine;
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("5"))
            {
                strBatchHeader = strLine;
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("6"))
            {
                strEntry = strLine;
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("8"))
            {
                strBtchcntrl = strLine;
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("9"))
            {
                strFileCntrl = strLine;
            }
        }

  string strQuery = "insert into tblfiles(FName, FData,FileHeader,BatchHeader,Entry,BtchEntry,FileControl) values (@_FName,@_FData,@_FileHeader,@_BtchHeader,@_EntryDets,@_BtchCntrl,@_FileCntrl)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FData", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = bytes;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FileHeader", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strFileHeader;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_BtchHeader", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strBatchHeader;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_EntryDets", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strEntry;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_BtchCntrl", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strBtchcntrl;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FileCntrl", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strFileCntrl;
        InsertUpdateData(cmd);
```

But this will insert the latest to the DB but i would like to save each and every line as per i stated

Comment: You've tagged this as `homework`. Can you provide more details of the assignment (the problem you are trying to solve) and what code you have **now** that doesn't work. We can't be expected to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Chris : First of all I just want to know how can i insert multiple data to a specified column in my DB

Comment: Why don't you just parse the file line by line in combination with a parameterized query you can set the values of the columns.

Comment: @ Bobby : Can i insert multiple data to the same column if i do like that

Comment: are you trying to associate several different entries of a particular type to one entity?  You'll just need to (nearly) duplicate entries in your table with just that one column changed, or decompose the table into multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - a column can only store one value per row. You could combine all your batch headers into one blob and store that as a single value, but you would have to be able to split them apart again when your read the data.

Instead - it looks as though:

1. each file starts with a '1' record and ends with a '9' record
2. each file contains zero or more batches
3. each batch starts with a '5' record and ends with an '8' record
4. each batch contains zero or more entries ('6' records)

If that is all correct, then you need 3 tables that would look something like:

File table:

```
Field         Type
-----------   --------
FileID        integer   # unique file ID - see AUTO_INCREMENT in the MySQL reference
FName         varchar
FData         longblob
FileHeader    longblob  # '1' record
FileControl   longblob  # '9' record
```

Batch table:

```
Field         Type
-----------   --------
FileID        integer   # references a row in the File table
BatchID       integer   # unique batch ID
BatchHeader   longblob  # '5' record
BatchControl  longblob  # '8' record
```

BatchEntry table:

```
Field         Type
-----------   --------
BatchID       integer   # references a row in the Batch table
EntryId       integer   # unique file ID
Entry         longblob  # '6' record
```

That should get you started. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Stringbuilder and append the required lines to that string builder and write them to the DB instead of using strings. Seperating each column will be a tough one to retrieve the data if you need. So declare a string builder and append the lines to each and every one you required and after all write to the DB

```
string strFileHeader = string.Empty;
StringBuilder strBatchHeader=new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder strEntry=new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder strBtchcntrl=new StringBuilder();
string strFileCntrl = string.Empty;


using (StreamReader srRead = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (srRead.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            strLine = srRead.ReadLine();
            if (strLine.StartsWith("1"))
            {
                strFileHeader = strLine;
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("5"))
            {

                strBatchHeader.AppendLine(strLine);
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("6"))
            {
                strEntry.AppendLine(strLine);
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("8"))
            {
                strBtchcntrl.AppendLine(strLine);
            }
            if (strLine.StartsWith("9"))
            {
                strFileCntrl = strLine;
            }
        }

 string strQuery = "insert into tblfiles(FName, FData,FileHeader,BatchHeader,Entry,BtchEntry,FileControl) values (@_FName,@_FData,@_FileHeader,@_BtchHeader,@_EntryDets,@_BtchCntrl,@_FileCntrl)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FData", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = bytes;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FileHeader", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strFileHeader;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_BtchHeader", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strBatchHeader.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_EntryDets", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strEntry.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_BtchCntrl", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strBtchcntrl.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FileCntrl", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = strFileCntrl;
        InsertUpdateData(cmd);
```

Comment: Nice idea but i would like to know the alternative